# Envoy rate limit config

Tags: grpc, rate-limiting, envoyproxy

I am trying to figure out how to set the rate limit in front-envoy to other services.

I referred their documentation but was unable to see how the configuration actually works. Also came across [lyft ratelimit](https://github.com/lyft/ratelimit) but here also how to use this config is not specified.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: There is a guide that someone has created [here](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/sre-resiliency-bolt-on-sidecar-rate-limiting-with-envoy-sidecar-5381bd4a1137) that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Envoy's rate limit filter relies on a global gRPC rate limit service such as Lyft's reference implementation. To use theirs, you'll have to build it. Thankfully, a contributor merged in a Dockerfile that you could use, but you'll need to add `CMD ./bin/ratelimit` to tell the Docker image to run when it starts.

The simplest way to explain the rate limit filter is that it allows for matching on rules that are configured *in* the actual rate limit service (i.e. the rate limits aren't actually set in Envoy config).

For example, given the Network rate limit filter config:

```
- name: envoy.ratelimit
  typed_config:
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.rate_limit.v2.RateLimit"
    stat_prefix: ratelimiter
    domain: myservice-ratelimiter
    descriptors:
    - entries:
      - key: path
        value: "/"
    failure_mode_deny: true
    rate_limit_service:
      grpc_service:
        envoy_grpc:
          cluster_name: my-ratelimit-cluster # define a Cluster pointing to the ratelimit service
```

You can then configure Lyft's ratelimit service as follows (see Lyft's example [config.yaml](https://github.com/lyft/ratelimit/blob/master/examples/ratelimit/config/config.yaml)):

```
domain: myservice-ratelimiter
descriptors:
  - key: path
    value: "/"
    rate_limit:
      unit: second
      requests_per_unit: 50
```

The configuration looks slightly different for the HTTP rate limit filter, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.